# SQL Trigger to send an email

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I need to créate a trigger in a SQL table to send an email if the inserted record meets certain conditions.
That is, I create the trigger in Table1 to send an email to X if in the inserted record the field IdCircuito= 53, IdTipoDoc = 45 and Gestor = 'Gest1'. Also, in the body of email message I want the value of a certain field of that inserted record to appear. I have done something like this but trigger always executes regardless of the inserted record:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SendEmail   
   ON  dbo.TitulosDoc 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN        
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TitulosDoc WHERE IdCircuito = 53 AND IdTipoDoc = 45 AND Gestor = 'Gest1')
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'rsg@gmail.com', 
      @subject = 'New requeriment', 
      @body = 'It's a new requeriment: ';
END
END
GO
```

In body is where I want show a literal text with the value of the field of inserted record:
@body = 'It's a new requeriment: ' + TitulosDoc.NombreDocumento;

Can somebody help me? Thank you

Comment: Instead of sending the email directly from your trigger you should instead populate a staging table of data that needs to be sent via email. Then create a process that queries the staging table every few minutes and sends the email. The rationale here is because you can have more than 1 row inserted at a time and you will need to loop those rows. Instead of putting looping and emails in your trigger we move that to a staging table to maintain performance of the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the inserted row you need to select from `INSERTED`.
Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SendEmail   
   ON  dbo.TitulosDoc 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN        
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @NombreDocumento VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT INSERTED.NombreDocumento 
                                         FROM INSERTED 
                                         WHERE INSERTED.IdCircuito = 53 
                                         AND INSERTED.IdTipoDoc = 45 
                                         AND INSERTED.Gestor = 'Gest1')

IF @NombreDocumento IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @recipients = 'rsg@gmail.com', 
      @subject = 'New requeriment', 
      @body = 'It''s a new requeriment: ' + @NombreDocumento;
END
END
GO
```

Comment: Since we can get multiple rows in inserted this is one of those times where a loop is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen!. Your answer works for me but with a little modification: in the body variable, you can't concatenate literal text with a variable in that way, you have to do this: set @body =  'It''s a new requeriment: ' + (select NombreDocumento from inserted);

Answer (score 0):

I would do what Sean Lange said... create a physical table called TempTitulosDoc, then insert your records to it that need to be sent through email. Do this in your trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.SendEmail   
   ON  dbo.TitulosDoc 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

BEGIN        
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TempTiulosDoc(field1, field2, EmailStatus)
    SELECT field1, field2, 0 AS EmailStatus --Email NOT sent
    FROM TitulosDoc 
    WHERE IdCircuito = 53 AND IdTipoDoc = 45 AND Gestor = 'Gest1'

END
END
GO
```

Create a stored procedure like this that loops through those records and sends an email. When done, update the TempTitlosDoc with a status of 1 signifying a sent email.

```
DECLARE @loopCount      INT
DECLARE @field1         VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @field2         VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @EmailStatus    int

--Create Temp Table
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    id int not null identity,
    field1 VARCHAR(10),
    field2 VARCHAR(10),
    EmailStatus int
)

--Insert Tasks to temp table
INSERT INTO #Temp (field1, field2, EmailStatus) 
SELECT field1, field2, EmailStatus
FROM dbo.TempTiulosDoc
WHERE Status = 0

--Set a loopCount for while loop
SET @loopCount = 1

--Use the while loop to check if we have any Tasks left to send
while ( exists(SELECT id FROM #Temp WHERE id = @loopCount) )
    BEGIN

        --Get current record in temp table
        SELECT  @field1             = field1,
                @field2             = field2,
                @EmailStatus        = EmailStatus
        FROM #Temp
        WHERE id = @loopCount

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
          @recipients = 'rsg@gmail.com', 
          @subject = 'New requeriment', 
          @body = 'It''s a new requeriment: ' + @NombreDocumento;

        --Update your work table with the status of 1 so it's not picked up again
        UPDATE teq
        SET teq.@EmailStatus = 1
        FROM dbo.TempTiulosDoc teq
        WHERE teq.id = @field1

        SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1

    END
```